# Calculate values outside of filter context - Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a few tables in Azure Analysis Model as shown below. I am using PowerBI to write a few measures.

DimProducts

```
+-----------------+--------+
| ProductId       | Name   |
+-----------------+--------+
|               1 |     p1 |
|               2 |     p2 |
|               3 |     p3 |
|               4 |     p4 |
|               5 |     p5 |
|               6 | `   p7 |
+-----------------+--------+
```

FactSales

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+
| ProductId |    Date     | Quantity |
+-----------+-------------+----------+
|         1 | 2016-02-01  |        1 |
|         1 | 2016-02-01  |        5 |
|         1 | 2016-02-05  |        7 |
|         2 | 2016-02-05  |        7 |
|         2 |  2016-02-08 |       10 |
+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

I need to find the sum quanity of sales.
I need to find the sum of quantity sold for the max date outside the filter. The date filter for example is 2016-02-08.
The max date below this filter is 2016-05-02 and the sum quantity for productid 2 is 7(4th line in factSales table).
How could i write a measure for this?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximal date prior to the date selected and then use that to replace your filter context inside `CALCULATE`.

```
MaxDateSum =
VAR SelectedDate = MAX ( FactSales[Date] )
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( FactSales[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( FactSales[Date] ), FactSales[Date] < SelectedDate )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( FactSales[Quantity] ), FactSales[Date] = MaxDate )
```